# Android read Assets resources in native code, special character in the end

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am using the following code to read files in /assets/ folder,

```
//AAssetManager* mgr  from parameter.
    AAsset* asset = AAssetManager_open(mgr, filen_ame, AASSET_MODE_BUFFER);
if (NULL == asset) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "hdrijni", "_ASSET_NOT_FOUND_");
    return;
}
long size = AAsset_getLength(asset);
char * buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
int byteRead = AAsset_read(asset, buffer, size);
AAsset_close(asset);
```

I can get the content, but sometimes the content appends some special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this problem not because of Asset Manager, but with the shader code I am using.

After I read the shader content, I will create the shader like:

```
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(type);
glShaderSource(shader, 1, &buffer2, NULL);
```

Asset buffer or content buffer transfered by JNI might be not NULL
terminated, so you need to use 'length' parameter when calling
glShaderSource.  -- From others.

Just change 
        glShaderSource(shader, 1, &buffer2, &length);